# What are the compelling resons to update SQL Server name to a real one after its changing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, configuration, maintenance

Took the job of monitoring and tuning a few dozens SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Ed. SP1 (64 bit) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Ed. running inside virtual machines.

All of them on running

```
select @@servername
select * from sys.servers
```

return  the same machine autogenerated during Windows setup name `WIN-MIQD9ME78FK`.

[image: SQL Server name]

These production servers works over 2 (probably much more) years.

As far as I can guess the hosts' name were changed after installing SQL Server.

What are the compelling reasons for [updating SQL Servers name for its real host names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)?

And which surprises should I be ready for after such changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using SQL Server Replication or remote jobs (MSX Jobs) then it really doesn't matter all that much.  It's a bit annoying when the server names don't match when you run select @@servername, but it's really not that big a deal for the most part.

Comment: It's also very easy and, unless the old server name is hard-coded somewhere, harmless to fix.

Comment: The main problem is in down-time since, it requires restarting the instances and the fear of unforeseen consequences

Comment: If there's a problem after changing it, just change it back and restart the service again.